# Why do all the normals to this parametrized surface pass through the $z$-axis?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

> Show that the normals to a parametrized surface given by
> $$
> \mathbf{x}(u, v) 
> = \bigl( f(u) \cos v, f(u) \sin v, g(u) \bigr), 
> \quad f(u) \neq 0,\; g' \neq 0
> $$
> all pass through the $z$-axis.

I have calculated normal as
$$
\mathbf{N}(u,v) 
= \bigl( -g'(u) \cos v, -g'(u) \sin v, f'(u) \bigr)
$$
for the following problem, but I could not conclude why it must pass through the $z$-axis. Thanks!

Comment: That's a [surface of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution). You calculated the *normal vector* at the surface point $x(u, v)$, and the problem means the whole *straight line* which is spanned by the normal and passes through $x(u,v)$. Note that the projections of the normal vector and of the radius vector on $Oxy$ are proportional, so the straight line in question will either intersect $Oz$ or be parallel to it. The second option might be eliminated using the information given in the problem statement...

Answer (score 1):

Actually the above comment would suffice as an answer. But I thought maybe you would like to see the answer in a literal way. If you are familiar with the concept of Plücker coordinates you can write such coordinates for the z-axis which is simply

$$X_1 := (\omega_1,v_1),\quad\quad\quad \text{where}\quad\quad\quad \omega_1 = (0,0,1),\quad\text{and}\quad v_1 = (0,0,0)$$

where $\omega_i$ stands as the **direction** of the line while $v_i$ stands as the **moment** of the line.

The normal lines of the surface of revolution as Plücker coordinates are

$$X_2 :=  (\omega_2,v_2),\quad\quad\quad \text{where}\quad\quad\quad \omega_2 = N(u,v),\quad\text{and}\quad v_2 = x(u,v) \times N(u,v)$$

If two lines intersect the **reciprocal product** of their plücker coordinates should vanish:

$$X_1 \circ X_2 = \langle \omega_1, v_2\rangle + \langle \omega_2, v_1\rangle = 0$$

Which is the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comment by @Amateur_Algebraist, we want to consider the line spanned by the normal vector:
$$
\mathbf{x} + t\mathbf{N}, \quad t \in \mathbb{R}, 
$$
and show that for some $t$, it intersects the $z$-axis.

How do we characterize the $z$-axis? The set of points where $x=0$ and $y=0$. So for each point on the surface parametrized by $(u, v)$, we need to find $t$ such that
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
\bigl( f(u) - t g'(u) \bigr) \cos v &=0 \\
\bigl( f(u) - t g'(u) \bigr) \sin v &=0 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
The point with parameter

> $$ t = \frac{f(u)}{g'(u)} $$

works (and it's guaranteed to exist by the given hypotheses).

Comment: Thanks to all! Now, I understand.